Is there any way to increase the lifetime of a github nuget package token?
I have a nuget package that is set up using github actions. This is deployed privately to a github package manager, in which I am able to authenticate to the nuget source where I can provide a personal access token to receive access. This restores and builds perfectly for anywhere from 30m -> 1hr, in which case it starts failing, and the only way to solve this is to go into nuget package manager and refresh. This is taking me out of my workflow, and is annoying to continuously do.
Are there any ways to make this source personal access token last longer, or are there alternative methods to authenticating to the github package sources?
Steps I am using in my actions:
        steps:
          - name: "Add Package Source"
            run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MY-GITHUB/index.json --name github --username 'ADMIN-USER' --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}} --store-password-in-clear-text

          - name: "Download Artifact"
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
            with:
              name: package
              path: ./src/package
        
          - name: "Publish Nuget Package"
            run: dotnet nuget push ./src/package/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.MY-PAT-SECRET }} -s github


Adding that package source to nuget is what triggers the PAT. Additionally in other build pipelines this works perfectly fine.
